# Can select UIButton only at the top

Tags: iphone, uibutton

I have a `UIButton` with a Background Image, the button frame is (150x200) and the button will be displayed right. When i try to touch the Button nothing happens except when I touch at the top of the `UIButton`. Then the whole button is highlighted and the touch event will be called. I checked the framesize, boundssize and set the `UserInteractionEnabled` to `YES`. Is there a special TouchFrame or something else? 
Can anyone tell how to fix this problem?
Thanks!!

this is my code:

```
CGRect thumbRect = CGRectMake(0, 20, 150, 200);
self.thumbButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:thumbRect];
[self.thumbButton setBackgroundImage:firstPage.image300 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.thumbButton addTarget:self action:@selector(imageClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Comment: You have taken your button from XIB or programmatically ?

Comment: I did it programmatically. for the first time ;)

Comment: show your code how you added your button ?

Answer (score 0):

Set back ground color for all view and then see which view is coming above that button its happening because of frame or your view.

Comment: and check your button property it should be UIControlEventTouchUpInside

Comment: Hehehe @amitsoni , It hink this has nothing to do with the background color of the View .... u agree dont u ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the property

```
[Button setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

You did not add this did you ? Or you might have added something else to the state like

```
forState:UIControlEventTouchUpOutside
```

This would make the function call if and only if you touch outside the `UIButton`

Please check this out :)